# Copy a file with a name criteria using WinSCP scripting

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have a `Test` folder that contains multiple file with two types of filenames as below:

```
Cycle2605.zip
Cycle2605_P.zip
Cycle2705.zip
Cycle2705_P.zip
```

What I manage to do is, move all the file from the folder to other server via WinSCP SFTP as shown in the code below.

```
open sftp://user:password@hostname/ -hostkey="ecdsa-sha2*******"
put D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Test /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in
exit
```

But how do I move file that in the filename not contain `_P` to the destination instead of move all file?

```
open sftp://user:password@hostname/ -hostkey="ecdsa-sha2*******"
if <filename not contain _p> echo put D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Test /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude files [matching certain pattern](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) with [`-filemask` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#filemask):

```
put -filemask=|*_P.zip D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Test /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in
```

---

Or you can pick only the files you want, if your file name convention allows, e.g.:

```
put -filemask=Cycle????.zip D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Test /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in
```

In this case, it's easier to use a Windows wildcard directly in the [source path](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#remarks):

```
put D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Test\Cycle????.zip /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in/
```